# malformed line in source list, getdeb

Tags: software-sources

```
E:Malformed line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list (URI)
```

^^ This is what I get back, earlier I was trying to get Pokemon Online to install properly, and it wasn't working, so I tried to get getdeb, now it won't check or show updates without giving me the message above, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Now it keeps sending me the information that it's experiencing an error continually.

EDIT 2:
These are the contents of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list`:

```
deb http://    archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu precise-getdeb apps  
deb  
http://   archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu saucy-getdeb apps  
deb http://    archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu saucy-getdeb apps  
deb http://    archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu precise-getdeb games
```

Comment: The error is telling you you have a bad line in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list`. Please post the contents of that file. Also, "this is what I get back" is not exactly clear. You get that when you do _what_?

Comment: http://i60.tinypic.com/2e50eht.png Here, exactly what it says to me when i try to click, "show updates"

Comment: Thanks, you had not said you were clicking on "show updates". You still haven't shown the contents of the file I asked for though, that is the reason for your error. Specifically, the second line of the file has a format error but I can't tell you what it is without seeing the file.

Comment: Okay, where do I go to find that, if you couldn't tell, I'm pretty new to Ubuntu and don't have much any idea what I'm doing, especially since the OS updated to something a bunch of numbers ahead of what was detailed in the manual that the disk came with.

Comment: The file _is_ at `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list`, just open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), paste this: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list`, then hit enter and add the results to your question. Ping me (@terdon) if you want to let me know you have done so.

Comment: deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu precise-getdeb apps
deb
http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu saucy-getdeb apps
deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu saucy-getdeb apps
deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu precise-getdeb games

@terdon

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add extra info, it is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. I can't tell where each line ends for example.

Comment: edited, but it wasn't behaving so I placed tally marks between the individual lines.

Comment: See [here](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) for help on using the editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read the question correctly, your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list` looks like this:

```
deb http:// archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu precise-getdeb apps
deb
http:// archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu saucy-getdeb apps
deb http:// archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu saucy-getdeb apps
deb http:// archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu precise-getdeb games
```

If so, the problem is indeed on the second line. `deb` lines have this format:

```
deb http://repo.url.com repo_section(s)
```

So, open that file in an editor using `sudo`

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list
```

Then, edit the file so that it looks like this:

```
deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu precise-getdeb apps
deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu saucy-getdeb apps
deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu saucy-getdeb apps
deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu precise-getdeb games
```

Make sure each lines starts with `deb` and that there are no spaces between `http://` and `archive`.